PyCharm + Transformers: Unable to Use Breakpoints with `Trainer()`
I'm used to developing and debugging with PyCharm. I've recently started using the HuggingFace ecosystem (transformers, accelerate, trl), specifically following an example of the vanilla Trainer() class in transformers (which uses accelerate under the hood, I believe). I find that:

If I set a breakpoint, PyCharm displays Collecting data... and never updates
I already enabled Gevent compatible; this made no difference
If I resume executing from that breakpoint, PyCharm "continues executing" but no progress is made. The process just hangs. No subsequent breakpoint will be triggered and I cannot pause the process
The most relevant GitHub issue I could find was not able to help me
I tried setting the environment variable ACCELERATE_DEBUG_MODE=1 as suggested here but this has no apparent effect.

Does anyone know how to successfully debug HuggingFace-ecosystem code using PyCharm?
